# url redirect in mvc . i want to redirect localhost/windshield-replacement.html to localhost/greenvalleyaz

Tags: php, url, model-view-controller, url-routing, phalcon-routing

My applications is now in phalcon php framework. I want to redirect a url which contain .html at the end. To redirect, I wrote the controller name as `WindshieldReplacementHtmlController.php` but because of the dot in between I could not redirect. How can I solve this?

Redirect from:

```
localhost/windshield-replacement.html
```

to

```
localhost/greenvalleyaz
```

When I type `localhost/windshield-replacement-html` its redirecting to the target but when i use `localhost/windshield-replacement.html` its not detecting the controller. 
is it the correct way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC you should not show the View Directly

you have to access a controller action --> in action you have to render view

In the Example I want to show `user/order.phtml` 
I will access this page from Browser  `localhost/appname/user/orders`

UserController.php

```
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;

class UserController {

    function ProfileAction(){  //access localhost/appname/controller/profile
    }

    function loginAction(){ //access localhost/appname/controller/profile
    }

    function ordersAction(){ //access localhost/appname/controller/orders

         $view = new View();

         // Setting views directory
         $view->setViewsDir('app/views/');

         $view->start();

         // Shows recent posts view (app/views/user/orders.phtml)
         $view->render('user', 'orders');
         $view->finish();

         // Printing views output
         echo $view->getContent();

    }
}
```

Refer : [Phalcon_Mvc_View](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/3.0.1/api/Phalcon_Mvc_View.html)